# Combining two query results (aggreagtions) into one visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I got two queries where each of them returns an (for my case) correct aggregation.

```
POST /my_target_0001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "locked": true      
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "abc_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "lastModified",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
POST /my_target_0002/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "xyz_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "lastModified",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the data is aggregated by day. Now I want to display a histogram which shows me the quotient of `abc` and `xyz` for each bucket of the same day. As far as I understood I need two steps to finally visualize the data, first build a query which return what I want and secondly put it somewhere in the visualization. So therefore I have two question:

*How do I combine the two queries in order to get the result described above?*

*How do I build a visualization form the query result?*

I'm pretty new to elastic search an kibana

Comment: You want the quotient of `abc` over `xyz` ?

For `Day 1` `abc=12`, `xyz=20` so you would display a mark at `0.6` ? Or you would like then side by side

Comment: @Paulo I want the `0.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

You will have to use kibana's [Timelion visualisation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/timelion.html).

**visualize library -> create visualization -> Aggregation based -> Timelion**

## Example

In this case I am using the same index twice but feel free to use yours.

I am plotting overtime, the ratio between the average number of bytes and the max number of bytes per buckets.

```
.es(index= kibana_sample_data_logs,
    timefield='@timestamp',
    metric='avg:bytes')
   .divide(
       .es(index= kibana_sample_data_logs,
           timefield='@timestamp',
           metric='max:bytes'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works fine for me, I just had to add a filter via `q='locked:true',` as an additional parameter and I use `metric='count:lastModified'`